# How do I restrict access to my aws s3 object per my site account?

Tags: amazon-s3

How do I restrict access to my aws s3 object per my site account?

Here's the scenario:

- I have a web app that allow users to post a message with images to a particular web app account.
- That user is of course a member of that account.
- All of posted images will be saved on AWS S3

Q: How can I restrict non-member for directly accessing (typing the s3 url from the browser) the posted images? (Of course I can't avoid copying the image)

Answer (score 0):

To prevent someone from loading the image outside the context of your website you could add an [HTTP Referrer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-4) condition to your bucket policy.

To totally secure the images you could make the S3 bucket private and use [pre-signed URLs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) to serve each image request.